# Can users upload files into a S3 bucket without frontend experience or users having access to AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, data-ingestion

I am looking to create an AWS solution where a lambda function will transform some excel data from a S3 bucket.  When thinking about how I'm going to create the architecture background, I need to think of a way where I can get non-technical users, which don't have access to the AWS account, to upload data into a S3 bucket.  One possible solution is using an S3 API and creating a UI to allow the users to upload the data.  However, I do not have much experience with front end programming skills such as JS and HTML. Are there any other possible solutions we can use?

I've thought about creating a simple UI and using a S3 API to ingest data into the bucket but I do not have front end programming experience.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

- Serve a web page from somewhere (S3?) and have them upload via the browser, or
- Give them a simple program like [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/) and they can drag & drop files, or
- Setup the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on their computer and have them double-click a script file to sync local disk folder to the s3 bucket, or
- Use Dropbox and [Invoke Lambda Function on New File from Dropbox - Pipedream](https://pipedream.com/apps/dropbox/integrations/aws/lambda-invoke-function-with-aws-api-on-new-file-from-dropbox-api-int_avso6rR)

The main thing to think about is **how you want to secure the upload**. For example, do they need to authenticate first, or do you want anyone in the world to be able to upload to the bucket (not a good idea!). Should each user have their own IAM User credentials, or should they authenticate to an application that manages its own logins?

Also, have a think about what you want to happen *after* they upload the file. If they need to download something after the file has been processed, then you'll need a way to **'give back' the new file**.

Comment: Thank you John, this is all very helpful. I plan on using SES to send the transformed file back to the user.

Comment: In that case, you'll also need a way to identify _which_ user made the upload, and their email address.